# Material UI apply complete custom theme to documentation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a complete custom Material UI theme using global overrides as recommended here: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override

Example:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My question is how do I get a copy of the Material UI documentation with my custom theme applied? https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

Some considerations:

- I want the Material UI docs to be updatable (i.e. follow the latest release)
- Essentially an exact copy of the Material UI docs wrapped in my custom theme

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: Creating a custom design system built on top of material ui. Need some central documentation for other developers to use.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this [mui-theme-creator](https://bareynol.github.io/mui-theme-creator/) from MUI's latest documentation https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-builder which would help.

However, this is not yet on v5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).